# C++ dll injection failed

Tags: c++

I am on a window10 environment, coding in vistual studio x64

Here is the dll injection target code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string choose;
    int hello = 200;
    while (true) {
        cout << &hello << endl;
        cout << "[+] Value : " + to_string(hello) << endl;
        cout << "[!] new Value : ";
        cin >> choose;
        if (choose == "show")
        {
            cout << "[+] Value : " + to_string(hello) << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            hello = stoi(choose);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the injector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

using namespace std;

bool WINAPI InjectDynamicLibrary(DWORD processId, LPCTSTR dllPath)
{
    HANDLE hProc = NULL;
    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processId);
    if (hProc == NULL)
    {
        cout << "[!] Opening process failed!!\n";
        return FALSE;
    }
    LPTSTR psLibFileRemote = NULL;
    psLibFileRemote = (LPTSTR)VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, lstrlen(dllPath) + 1,
        MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (psLibFileRemote == NULL)
    {
        printf("[-] VirtualAllocEx failed.\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    if (WriteProcessMemory(hProc, psLibFileRemote, (void *)dllPath, 
        lstrlen(dllPath) + 1, NULL) == 0)
    {
        printf("[-] WriteProcessMemory Failed.\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pfnStartAddr = (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)
        GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"Kernel32"), "LoadLibraryA");
    if (pfnStartAddr == NULL)
    {
        printf("[-] GetProcAddress Failed.\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc,
        NULL,
        0,
        pfnStartAddr,
        psLibFileRemote,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (hThread == NULL)
    {
        printf("[-] CreateRemoteThread Failed.\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    printf("[*] Inject Succesfully.\n");
    return TRUE;
}

DWORD FindProcessId(LPCSTR processName)
{
    DWORD ProcessID = 0;
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(0, processName);
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &ProcessID);
    if (ProcessID == 0)
    {
        cout << "[!] Couldn't Find window\n";
    }
    return ProcessID;
}

int main()
{
    LPCSTR injecttargetpath = "C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\C++\\C test\\x64\\Debug\\C test.exe";
    LPCTSTR dllpath = L"C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\hackeddll\\Debug\\hackdll.dll";
    InjectDynamicLibrary(
        FindProcessId(injecttargetpath),
        dllpath);
    system("pause");
}
```

And here is the Dll code

```
#include "pch.h"
#include<Windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    if (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, "Hello", "HELLO", MB_OK);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The inject Successfully message show up, but nothing happened.

I have tried to turn my permission level into require administrator, but it doesn't really help.

What is the problem?

Comment: You get the remote thread call `LoadLibraryA` (expecting a `char*` parameter) but inject a Unicode string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are compiling with `UNICODE` defined, making `LPCTSR` be `const wchar_t*`, but your injection code is not taking into account that `sizeof(wchar_t)=2` bytes, it Is assuming that `LPCTSR` is `const char*` instead, where `sizeof(char)=1` byte. As such, it ends up writing only 1/2 of the DLL's Unicode file path into the target process. And then the injection is calling `LoadLibraryA()` passing it a (partial) Unicode file path, which will fail.

You need to change the injection to multiply the result of `lstrlen()+1` by `sizeof(TCHAR)` when allocating and filling the remote memory, and to use `LoadLibraryW()` when `UNICODE` is defined.

You also need to cleanup after yourself. If `VirtualAllocEx()` succeeds, you need to call `VirtualFreeEx()` to free the memory you allocated. If `CreateRemoteThread()` succeeds, you need to call `WaitForSingleObject()` to wait for `LoadLibrary(A|W)` to finish running, and then call `CloseHandle()` to release the thread you created.

---

On a side note:

You are searching for the target process by looking for an active window whose title text is the target file path, which likely does not exist. You should instead be enumerating running processes, looking at the EXE file paths that each process was created from.  See [Process Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-enumeration), [Enumerating All Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes), and [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes) on MSDN for how to get those paths.

Also, `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is too many permissions to ask for. You don't need that many rights to perform DLL injection. All you need are: `PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD`, `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`, `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION`, `PROCESS_VM_WRITE`, and `PROCESS_VM_READ` - the bare minimum needed to call `WriteProcessMemory()` and `CreateRemoteThread()`. Don't ask for more rights than you really need.

Comment: I have made a little change, but it seem like not working. `psLibFileRemote = (LPTSTR)VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, (lstrlen(dllPath)+1) * sizeof(TCHAR), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);` 


And this


 `PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pfnStartAddr = (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"Kernel32"), "LoadLibraryW")`

Comment: @BearBench you updated the call to `VirtualAllocEx()` to account for `sizeof(TCHAR)`, but did you also update the call to `WriteProcessMemory()` to do the same?